# How to transfer "trasfer function" from simulink to matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hello guys I need an advice. As you can see in the picture I have transfer function which I want to transfer to matlab workspace. Parameters are set to a1 = 1, a2 = 10, K = 5. 
[Block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztAsF.png)

In "matlab function" block I have code which is below. The code will transfer my "transfer function" into the matlab as a constant (Just one number). But I would like to that it would transfer as individual parameters. So it should return me back same parameters which I set in the beginning (a1 = 1, a2 = 10, K = 5). Can anyone help me?

```
    function tfout  = fcn(tfin)
%#codegen
coder.extrinsic('evalin', 'assignin')

tfout=tfin;           

assignin('base','tfout',tfout); % Assign value back to workspace
```

Comment: At every simulation time step your code is writing the value of the signal being fed into the MATLAB Function block to the workspace.  It has nothing whatsoever to do with the coefficients of the transfer function itself.  What are you trying to achieve?  If you are intending to change the value of the transfer function coefficients at each time step (or at least sometimes) then you are going about it in almost the worst possible way.

Comment: I have to make adaptive pid controller (adaptive = parameters change over time) in the Simulink that's why I'm trying to find way how to change parameters in transfer function. Because I have to identify data using recursive least square method which I've already programmed in "matlab script". Recursive least square method will provide me transfer function, but transfer function is always different, it depends on data. And then I have compute parametrs for PID controller.

Comment: And I think it's easier to compute parametrs in "matlab function" using the formulas (for example zigler-nichols method), than using blocks in simulink.

Comment: I agree, and didn't suggest not to calculate the parameters in m-code.  But writing them to the workspace and trying to read them back into a Transfer Function block is not the right way to implement a time varying transfer function.  You should output the parameter values from the m-code (i.e. as signals in the model) and then use those signal values as input to Product block's appropriately interconnected to form the transfer function required.